# Looping through a list and checking for contents?

Tags: c#, list, bots, discord, discord.net

I'm trying to set up a simple command for entering all callers into a .txt file, everything is working out nicely except for the part where I want to loop through the list and check that no one is trying to enter more than once, it's not causing any problems to the application itself but it's not doing what it's supposed to do.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
string filePath = Secret.Secrets.fileDestination;

            var username = msg.Author.Username;
            //ulong
            var ID = msg.Author.Id;

            string IDout = ID.ToString();

            List<string> entries = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();

            if(entries.Contains(IDout))
            {
                await msg.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"{msg.Author.Mention}, you have already been entered.");

                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
                Console.WriteLine($"Denied entry for {msg.Author.Mention}");

                return;
            }

            entries.Add($"{username}, {ID}");

            File.WriteAllLines(filePath, entries);

            await msg.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"{msg.Author.Mention} has been entered!");
```

Comment: Maybe there is a Envoirment.NewLine at the end of an entrie string.

Comment: Checked that already, not the case

Comment: Well then use the debugger and check what the value of IDout is and how the List looks like.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong there either, this is what it prints out: http://prntscr.com/lif0a3

Comment: When I say debugging, I mean setting a breakpoint and check each iterations for errors. You might wanna write your Contains method yourself to see whats going on there